# How to get the heatmapInstance of heatmap-vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm using this [Vue-Wrapper](https://github.com/nqdy666/heatmapjs-vue) of [heatmap.js](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) and I don't know how I can call the heatmapInstance "h337" in my Vue-Component.
I canuse the functionallity, but I can't call methods such as getValueAt, because I don't know the insatnce.

EDIT: Updated my post with some code.
Here is my component where I want to call th methods and at some point (in mouseposition() function) I need to call the method "getValueAt" (named it heatmapInstance) and the heatmap-vue.js is imported in my main.js as webpack.

```xml
<template>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="6">
            <v-card min-height="46.5em" elevation="3">
              <v-card-text class="px-0">
                <v-col cols="12" xl="6">
                  <span class="tooltip" style="display: none">tooltip</span>
                  <heatmapjs-vue
                    class="heatmapjs-container"
                    :max="max"
                    :min="min"
                    :data="heatData"
                  >
                    <v-img
                      contain
                      height="100%"
                      class="feet"
                      src="../assets/test_links_fuss-cutOut.svg"
                    ></v-img>
                  </heatmapjs-vue>
                </v-col>
       ...
   

     </template>
        <script>
        export default {
          data: () => ({
            min: null,
            max: null,
            heatData: [],
            ...
          }),
          methods: {
           ...
            mouseposition() {
              this.demoWrapper = document.querySelector(".heatmapjs-container");
              this.tooltip = document.querySelector(".tooltip");
              this.demoWrapper.onmousemove = (ev) => {
                var x = ev.layerX;
                var y = ev.layerY;
        
                // getValueAt gives us the value for a point p(x/y)
                var value = heatmapInstance.getValueAt({
                  x: x,
                  y: y,
                });
                console.log(value);
              };
            },
          },
          mounted() {
            this.mouseposition();
          },
          created() {},
        };
        </script>
        <style>
        ...
        </style>
```

Comment: Please provide some code. without it it's almost impossible to tell, where the problem is.

Comment: looking at the documentation it seems like you don't need to know the instance, since the vue component has it's own methods like getValueAt that are wired with the instance created in the component. 
You can try reading it with `component.heatmap` It's not a predefined data field in the component, but will be set in the mounted() hook `mounted(){this.heatmap = h337.create(...)}`

Comment: @D.Schaller Thanks. I updated my post with some code. Sorry but I'm at this point were I can not see the forest for the trees (I hope this phrase exists in english :D). I really have no idea how I get access to these methods with my code, without the instance

Comment: I see. the heatmap-vue component should give you all information and should have all the methods you are looking for. the heatmap-vue component has a change event you can listen to. I suggest to look into the heatmap code in github, that should give you all information you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and I didn't even think of "refs" in vue.js
Nevertheless here is the solution

```
    <heatmapjs-vue class="heatmapjsContainer" :data="heatData" ref="heatmap">
    </heatmapjs-vue>
    ...
    this.$refs.heatmap.getValueAt({
      x: x,
      y: y,
    });
```